# Loading a workflow stored as XAML in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

What is the syntax for loading a .NET 4.0 Beta2 workflow that was previously created and stored as XAML.

The WorkflowElement and WorkflowXamlServices classes no longer exist.  I am trying to do something like this (that worked in Beta 1):

```
WorkflowElement wf = WorkflowXamlServices.Load(File.OpenRead("Workflow.xaml")) as WorkflowElement;
```

Answer (score 10):

Found my own answer after further research.

The WorkflowElement and WorkflowXamlServices classes have been removed from Beta2.  The approach above requires the use of DynamicActivity and ActivityXamlServices.

```
DynamicActivity wf = ActivityXamlServices.Load("Workflow.xaml") as DynamicActivity;
```